# Saving individual fields in SQL Server database table that doesnt allow null values

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing an app that has a large form process.

Because of it's size I want to be able to individually save a copy of each field into the database as it is entered in.

The problem is, my table designs don't allow for null values. So how can I create a new table row with a primary key without filling out all fields?

My main table that all other tables that link to contains a draft boolean flag. Once a draft form is filled out, it can be submitted and saved as a finished form.

My current logic would be to have placeholder values that are only acceptable in the draft flagged form e.g -1 for integers, -1 for string etc. But on completion and submission of the form, it will confirm that no empty -1 placeholders still exist before being used as a submitted form.

This seems really dirty though.

Has anyone else had a similar issue and what did they do to resolve it? I would prefer not to allow NULL values into my tables.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And why do you prefer not to allow NULL values? NULL means exactly what you need - not filled in.

Answer (score 1):

use a 'staging' table to handle temporary/half filled form data.

when the user gets to the end then you will trigger the copy of the data from staging to the final table making all the needed checks/validation/whatever before putting the data in the real table.

the advantages i see:

1. your final table will not allow null
2. your final table will contain only valid data and no draft data (no need to check for placeholder once the data is in the final table)
3. your staging table will likely contain a small number of rows so the operations on that table should not add such a load on the system (**to be checked in advance!!!**)
4. if you require a login on your site/app then you can allow the user to get back later to complete the form

YMMV but this is a solution that worked fine form me and i really appreciate advantages 1 and 2. I don't like nullable fields because it happens that if null is allowed then it is null quite often and also don't like to mix temporary and final data if i can avoid it ^^

Comment: I also like this approach. My issue is my large form uses around 10 joined tables. Which would mean creating staging tables for each of the tables I plan to store draft content in.

Comment: any relation between tables may have to be replicated also. and links with external entities too (lookup tables and so on) even if you can leave them off and validate data before moving into the final table. the advantages **may** justify the effort but this is something that can be evaluated only knowing the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to save the user inputs as variables until all the form data has been received. At that point, you can safely insert the new row as a single insert using all of those variables without worrying about null values.

Additionally, using a single insert would reduce the overhead of several unnecessary db queries.

Comment: The main purpose of having draft fields being saved as the user completes the form is to be able to come back and finish the large form later. Storing the inputs as variables would mean once a session has ended, all the fields will be lost, and it would only create a false sense of security for the end user in thinking your fields were saved in a db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values for those columns which you want to save if no value will be given for those column default value set for those column will be inserted.But be sure to update all these columns because it will show default data when you will get data from db.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] (
[Id]          INT          NOT NULL,
[Category]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Default Value',
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I had currently planned to do it. It would mean a lot of dirty data though as default values would be entered until they were filled in. That's why I had posted to see opinions and other practices carried out.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the question for a different solution to the one you posted. As I mentioned, I am looking for a solution other than this, as it is currently all I think I can do but do not want dirty information.